# Google Cloud Storage bucket list_blobs prefix is too broad

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using the Google Cloud Storage Python API to gather the list of files contained in specific subdirectories within Cloud Storage.

```
bucket.list_blobs(prefix='abc')
```

However, the issue with this is that I only want to gather the list of files within:

bucket/abc/

However, what's being called is:

bucket/abc/
AND
bucket/abc-123/

How do I ensure that the prefix is to be used as an exact match? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want only blobs that are directly under `bucket/abc`? And nothing from the sub directories?

Comment: I want all blobs within all sub-directories within bucket/abc.

E.g. bucket/abc/1/, bucket/abc/2/, bucket/abc/3/, bucket/abc/test.txt should all have their blobs listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a `/` to the end of your prefix should prevent matching with other files/directories starting with same prefix as your target directory.

```
bucket.list_blobs(prefix='abc/')
```

Comment: Ahh I thought I'd tried this, but just tried again, and hey presto! Must have cocked something else up. Cheers.